# jQuery returns UNDEFINED or ON as Input Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem to get input value with jQuery.

Final **Edit:**
problem solved.
damnnn, i missed

> =

for value attribute in input tag,

i struggled a lot with this silly mistake.. laughing emoji..

---

If i use

```
$("input[name=xxx]:checked").attr("value");
```

it returns UNDEFINED

If i use

```
$("input[name=xxx]:checked").val();
```

it returns ON(an error, not value.)

**Edit:**
Input created dynamically with js.

```
<div id="ab">
<input type="checkbox" name="aaa" value="apple">apple
<input type="checkbox" name="aaa" value="banana">banana
<input type="checkbox" name="aaa" value="grapes">grapes
<input type="checkbox" name="aaa" value="pista">pista
<input type="checkbox" name="aaa" value="badam">badam
<input type="checkbox" name="aaa" value="fruit">fruit
</div>
<div id="abcd"></div>
```

and after checked some of above, then below one,

```
var data="";
$('input[name=aaa]:checked').each(function() {
data += $(this).attr('value')+": <label class=\"badge badge-secondary mx-1\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"xxx\" value\""+$(this).attr('value')+"\">A</label><label class=\"badge badge-secondary rounded-circle mx-1\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"yyy\" value\""+$(this).attr('value')+"\">B</label>";
});
$('#abcd').html(data);
```

that one created content well correctly, but finally have problem in getting value of that checked radios,(user can select only two among different items).

some jQuery functions doesn't work for dynamically generated content like,

```
$("#xxx").click(function(){});
```

that one doesn't work for content created with js after page load,

```
$("body").on("click", "#xxx", function(){});
```

this one works for content created with js after page load,

maybe, similarly, there will be another one to get Input values that are created with js after page load.

Comment: You have not set value attribute of input.
There is no attribute with the name value so First one gives undefined
The default value of checkable input is ON?OFF, So it gives ON in the second one

Comment: on is not a error, checkbox always return ON if checked and OFF it not checked.

Comment: if you want to return a true or false value, to determine whether it's checked or not, you could always use $('input[name="xxx"]').is(':checked'). You'll obviously need to attach an event listener to either listen for a change event (triggered when you check or uncheck the checkbox) or a click event for any buttons which are associated with the form you're creating.

Comment: @sandeep now you've edited it, that's pretty much a totally different question...anyway AndroidNoobie's answer covers it

Answer (score 1):

If a value isn't specified in the element, the default values of a checkbox are "on" and "off". If the checkbox is supposed to have some specific meaning, you can specify that in the `value` attribute.

For example, let's say we want the user to check the box if they're over 18 years old. We could do something like:

`<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="over 18"/>`

Then, when you query its value, `$("#checkbox").attr("value")`, you'll get "over 18".

If you don't want to specify a value that way, and you are using a label for the text next to the checkbox, you could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>
<label for="checkbox">Over 18?</label>
```

JS:

```
let text = $("label[for=checkbox]").text();
```

That will give you the label text, which is "Over 18?".

### Update

For OPs updated case, you might be able to use something like `$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});` via jQuery.

Example:

First, assign a class name to the class attribute when the checkboxes are created dynamically (e.g., `class = "your_class_name"`).

Then, do something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.your_class_name', function() {
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
    // Do something with selected element
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler, especially the section on **Direct and delegated event handlers**

Hope this helps.

Comment: @sandeep Updated my answer, hope it provides some help.

Answer (score -2):

Use 
`$("input[name=xxx]:checked")[0].value`

Because it may return array of inputs so you must select first from array

Comment: jQuery's .val() just provides a jQuery way of doing the same thing on the jQuery object, rather than selecting the DOM element like this. There should be no need to do this, it's functionally equivalent to what OP has already written.